# How to add objects of related tables in a backend app

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, server

i am writing a server app in django rest framework. it is a habit tracking app

here are the models

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
from users.models import User

class Habit(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    User = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='habits')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='',
                            verbose_name='Habit name')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

The user model is the default user model provided.

i need to create a habit object, that is linked to a user object.
how to write that in django rest framework.

```
class habit_list(APIView):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        habits = Habit.objects.all()
        serializer = HabitSerializer(habits, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = HabitSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

i need help in two things.

1. i have a hard time django rest framework genericviews. how many methods are there, how and when to use them, should objects be created inside serializers or inside views.
2. purely logic based question. how to create an object when it is linked to another through primary and foreign keys. should one be created first and then the linked object is to be created? what is the best approach.

i know its a very noob question. but please help me out